# Jekyll post links not including base url

Tags: apache, jekyll

I've added my baseurl to the config for Jekyll, but every permalink is not appending it.  I'm using Jekyll version 2.5.3 and Apache.

This is what the config looks like for all relevant content:

```
baseurl: /blog 
host: 0.0.0.0
permalink: /:year/:month/:day/:title
destination: /var/www/html/blog/_site/
```

The directory structure is the way it should, but the link request all show `localhost/2015/06...`

Does the routing need to be adjusted by Jekyll or Apache?

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly use `site.baseurl`. Jekyll doesn't automatically prepend it to urls.

```
<a href="{{site.baseurl}}{{post.url}">
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand this question might be outdated, but I also ran into this issue while hosting a Jekyll blog on GitHub pages.

You can use the `relative_url` [Liquid Filter provided by Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/) to automatically prepend any url with the `baseurl` configured in `_config.yml`.

Example:

```html
<a href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
```

> **Relative URL** 
> Prepend baseurl config value to the input to convert a URL path into a relative URL. This is recommended for a site that is hosted on a subpath of a domain.

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me, thank you! I didn't actually need to set the baseurl, though - just use the liquid filter.